# Extracting text from a website using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to fetch just the text of any website page content. I am using BeautifulSoup to do that.

I wrote a function like below:

```
def textClean(text): 
    """ This function takes the input text and cleans the HTML tags from it

    """

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    souptext=BeautifulSoup(text)
    print text
    print souptext.get_text()
```

This would print the original html source code and then the text of that too.

However here is a sample output I get:

**HTML output: (first print statement)**

```html
<p><img style="float:right;" src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/56eb68e791058427008b72e5-907-680/5550538407_c22babffba_b.jpg" alt="radar" data-mce-source="US Navy" data-mce-caption="Mineman Seaman Charles Bryan watches for contacts on the SPA 256 radar while on watch in the Combat Directive Center aboard the mine countermeasures ship USS Ardent (MCM 12)." data-link="https://www.flickr.com/photos/usnavy/5550538407/in/photolist-9stXG4-e6i1uU-e6i1tE-dLSiBQ-c9jmg7-f5LbtS-r9jw69-efvjaN-duNiV6-efpeEP-eW8Dg9-q1nZiQ-en2osX-duNiTa-njkj3s-eep3Mb-kUdU5g-9d7u4E-eeoYiC-fr2CuX-axHdte-fsVD3D-drHPeJ-9rAVac-cnMSiW-9vVcbN-enB31b-f23pKF-aBjveY-9rEhwY-9u6GZy-9rDT9L-bojAAh-9uiNiU-9AJSrB-9rFxwQ-bjkanD-aefpN9-ea2WB2-ea2WyR-a1tUoa-9rAUXZ-ea8Bf9-9Wm3Z8-9rNE7o-enB1YY-9rAUHX-ea2WpF-aNR7eD-9NX2pq" /><span class="source">US Navy</span></p><p>The United States has seen Chinese activity around a reef that China seized from the Philippines nearly four years ago that could be a precursor to more land reclamation in the disputed South China Sea, the U.S. Navy chief said on Thursday.</p>
```

**Second tet output: (second print statement)**

```
US NavyThe United States has seen Chinese activity around a reef that China seized from the Philippines nearly four years ago that could be a precursor to more land reclamation in the disputed South China Sea, the U.S. Navy chief said on Thursday.
```

If you see the text between the tag

```
<span class="source">US Navy</span></p>
```

is also getting extracted which I don't want as if we see the original article (link below) that text is not part of the original article.

I know get_text() would fetch all the texts, so I wanted a simple solution where we can specify to extract the text between paragraph tag but exclude the span tag as I don't think that text within span tag is part of the original text.

Here is the link to the article which I used.

[enter link description here](http://www.businessinsider.com/r-exclusive-us-sees-new-chinese-activity-around-south-china-sea-shoal-2016-3)

Edit1:

Gets the output like this: Each column is converted to unicode.

Here is the mapping function code I wrote to map each record of the Spark DataFrame and cleaning the HTML tags from the 'desc' column of the data frame.

```
def htmlParsing(x): 
    """ This function takes the input text and cleans the HTML tags from it

    """

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    #print text
    row=x.asDict()
    textcleaned=''
    souptext=BeautifulSoup(row['desc'])
    #souptext=BeautifulSoup(text)
    p_tags=souptext.find_all('p')
    for p in p_tags: 
        if p.string:
            #textcleaned+=p.string
            ret_list= (int(row['id']),(row['title']),(p.string))
            return ret_list
            #print p.string


sdf_cleaned=sdf_rss.map(htmlParsing)        

sdf_cleaned.take(4)
```

[(-33753621,
  u'Royal Bank of Scotland is testing a robot that could solve your banking problems (RBS)',
  u'If you hate dealing with bank tellers or customer service representatives, then the Royal Bank of Scotland might have a solution for you.'),
 (-761323061,
  u'Teen sexting is prompting an overhaul in child pornography laws',
  u'Rampant teen sexting has left politicians and law enforcement authorities around the country struggling to find some kind of legal middle ground between prosecuting students for child porn and letting them off the hook.'),
 (1405376555,
  u'Upon further review, China has started building a new project in the South China Sea',
  u'The United States has seen Chinese activity around a reef that China seized from the Philippines nearly four years ago that could be a precursor to more land reclamation in the disputed South China Sea, the U.S. Navy chief said on Thursday.'),
 (-1882022821,
  u'Ignition lock laws are reducing the rate of drunk-driving deaths',
  u'Reuters Health - States that require convicted drunk drivers to install ignition interlock devices in their cars had a 15 percent drop in alcohol-related crash deaths compared to states without these requirements, research shows.')]

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests, bs4
r = requests.get('http://www.businessinsider.com/r-exclusive-us-sees-new-chinese-activity-around-south-china-sea-shoal-2016-3')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

p_tags = soup.find_all('p')
for p in p_tags:
    if p.string:
        print(p.string)
```

> .string
>
> If a tag has only one child, and that child is a
>   NavigableString, the child is made available as .string:
>
> If a tag
>   contains more than one thing, then it’s not clear what .string should
>   refer to, so .string is defined to be None:

so, sting will only return p tags that only contain text.

out:

```
  The United States has seen Chinese activity around a reef that
  China seized from the Philippines nearly four years ago that
  could be a precursor to more land reclamation in the disputed
  South China Sea, the U.S. Navy chief said on Thursday.


  The head of U.S. naval operations, Admiral John Richardson,
  expressed concern that an international court ruling expected in
  coming weeks on a case brought by the Philippines against China
  over its South China Sea claims could be a trigger for Beijing to
  declare an exclusion zone in the busy trade route.


  Richardson told Reuters the United States was weighing responses
  to such a move.


  He said the U.S. military had seen Chinese activity around
  Scarborough Shoal in the northern part of the Spratly
  archipelago, about 125 miles (200 km) west of the Philippine base
  of Subic Bay.


  "I think we see some surface ship activity and those sorts of
  things, survey type of activity, going on. Thatâs an area of
  concern ... a next possible area of reclamation," he said.


  Richardson said it was unclear if the activity near the reef,
  which China seized in 2012, was related to the pending
  arbitration decision.


  He said China's pursuit of South China Sea territory, which has
  included massive land reclamation to create artificial islands
  elsewhere in the Spratlys, threatened to reverse decades of open
  access and introduce new "rules" that required countries to
  obtain permission before transiting those waters.


  He said that was a worry given that 30 percent of the world's
  trade passes through the region.


  Asked whether China could respond to the ruling by the court of
  arbitration in The Hague by declaring an air defense
  identification zone, or ADIZ, as it did farther north in the East
  China Sea in 2013, Richardson said: "Itâs definitely a concern."


  "We will just have to see what happens," he said. "We think about
  contingencies and â¦ responses."


  Richardson said the United States planned to continue carrying
  out freedom-of-navigation exercises within 12 nautical miles of
  disputed South China Sea geographical features to underscore its
  concerns about keeping sea lanes in the region open.


  The United States responded to the East China Sea ADIZ by flying
  B-52 bombers through the zone in a show of force in November
  2013.


  Richardson said he was struck by how China's increasing
  militarization of the South China Sea had increased the
  willingness of other countries in the region to work together,
  not just bilaterally, but also multilaterally.


  India and Japan joined the U.S. Navy in the Malabar naval
  exercise since 2014, and were slated to take part again this year
  in an even more complex exercise that will take place in an area
  close to the East and South China Seas.


  South Korea, Japan and the United States were also working
  together more closely than ever before, he said.


  Richardson said the United States would welcome the participation
  of other countries in joint patrols with the United States in the
  South China Sea, but those decisions needed to be made by the
  countries in question.


  He said the U.S. military saw good opportunities to build and
  rebuild relationships with countries such as Vietnam, the
  Philippines and India, which have all realized the importance of
  safeguarding the freedom of the seas.


  He cited India's recent hosting of an international fleet review
  that included 75 ships from 50 navies, and said the United States
  was exploring opportunities to increase its use of ports in the
  Philippines and Vietnam, among others - including the former U.S.
  naval base at Vietnam's Cam Ranh Bay.


  But he said Washington needed to proceed judiciously rather than
  charging in "very fast and very heavy," given the enormous
  influence and importance of the Chinese economy in the region.


  "We have to be sophisticated in how we approach this so that we
  donât force any of our partners into an uncomfortable position
  where they have to make tradeoffs that are not in their best
  interest," he said.


  "We would hope to have an approach that would ... include us a
  primary partner but not necessarily to the exclusion of other
  partners in the region," he said.

The United States has seen Chinese activity...
5 innovations in radiology that could impact everything from the Zika virus to dermatology
Keep tabs on the latest from Business Insider in our new Chrome Extension
Available on iOS or Android
```

Comment: This is a good answer. However I don't want to print the string. I want to save it back as dataset. However when I save it back I do get the unicode 'u' added to it and not plain string. How do I get rid of those?

Comment: Check Edit pls.

Comment: if you use python2, that it the default setting of python to add 'u' before string,  if you save data to file, the prefix 'u' will not show in file.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) expends all the tags and retrieves text beneath them.

You'll need to target your tag with something like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<p>
  <img style="float:right;" src="http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/56eb68e791058427008b72e5-907-680/5550538407_c22babffba_b.jpg" alt="radar" data-mce-source="US Navy" data-mce-caption="Mineman Seaman Charles Bryan watches for contacts on the SPA 256 radar while on watch in the Combat Directive Center aboard the mine countermeasures ship USS Ardent (MCM 12)." data-link="https://www.flickr.com/photos/usnavy/5550538407/in/photolist-9stXG4-e6i1uU-e6i1tE-dLSiBQ-c9jmg7-f5LbtS-r9jw69-efvjaN-duNiV6-efpeEP-eW8Dg9-q1nZiQ-en2osX-duNiTa-njkj3s-eep3Mb-kUdU5g-9d7u4E-eeoYiC-fr2CuX-axHdte-fsVD3D-drHPeJ-9rAVac-cnMSiW-9vVcbN-enB31b-f23pKF-aBjveY-9rEhwY-9u6GZy-9rDT9L-bojAAh-9uiNiU-9AJSrB-9rFxwQ-bjkanD-aefpN9-ea2WB2-ea2WyR-a1tUoa-9rAUXZ-ea8Bf9-9Wm3Z8-9rNE7o-enB1YY-9rAUHX-ea2WpF-aNR7eD-9NX2pq" />
  <span class="source">US Navy</span>
</p>
<p>
  The United States has seen Chinese activity around a reef that China seized from the Philippines nearly four years ago that could be a precursor to more land reclamation in the disputed South China Sea, the U.S. Navy chief said on Thursday.
</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print souptext.find_all('p')[1].get_text()
```

Comment: In your code, it only gives p[1]. For p[0] it will print US Navy too which is not what I want